# MySQL query JSON result is cut off

Tags: mysql, sql, json-arrayagg

When doing:

```
mysql -u case -p < MyQuery.sql
```

with the query being:

```
SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT('field1', field1, ...)) FROM db.table
```

the printed output is cut off at a random point, halfway a JSON tag. But it does end with `]`.

Apparently my 8000+ records are too much to handle for `JSON_ARRAYAGG`?

How can I work around this?

Comment: I don't see a mention of a limit in the documentation, but maybe it's affected by `group_concat_max_len`. What is this set to, and how does it compare to the size of your aggregate result.

Comment: Also try increasing `max_allowed_packet`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although it's not documented, apparently the setting [`group_concat_max_length`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_group_concat_max_len) also limits the size of the results of `JSON_xxxAGG()` functions. Increase this to allow larger results.

Comment: Amazing, setting `group_concat_max_len` to 10MB worked. My output was cut off at 1MB, which seems to be the default.